# For a given month and year how to get the second Sunday using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to calculate the second Sunday of a month.

using PowerShell script, how to get the second Sunday of a month for any given year?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: This will help you closer towards your answer: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7b8a6966-4ea8-4b0b-8ca6-c1c8545ecc54/find-date-on-second-tuesday-of-every-month?forum=dpmpowershell

Answer (score 2):

Using the integer value of Dayofweek as a (negative) offset 0..6 for Sunday..Saturday.

Get the Last Sunday of the previous Month and add 14

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\29\SO_55905125.ps1

function Get-Sunday2nd {
    param(
        [int]$Year=(Get-Date).Year,
        [int]$Month=(Get-Date).Month,
        [switch]$Time)
    $LastDayPrevMonth = (Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day 1).Date.AddDays(-1)
    $Sunday2nd = $LastDayPrevMonth.AddDays(14-[int]$LastDayPrevMonth.DayOfWeek)
    $Sunday2nd
}
```

---

```
Get-Sunday2nd 2019 5

Sonntag, 12. Mai 2019 00:00:00
```

---

```
Get-Sunday2nd -Year 2018 -Month 5

Sonntag, 13. Mai 2018 00:00:00
```